# Angular component mat-tree expands all nodes

Tags: tree, angular-material

The mat-tree example on Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-tree-test expands all tree nodes. Can you explain why? Can you correct it, so that it expands only one level?

Answer (score 0):

The ng-mat-tree-test example used angular 6.0.0-beta.5.
I updated the dependencies to angular 7.0.4 and it worked.
The updated example is under https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-tree-test-7.